# Подскажите библиотеку или плагин для построения donut -графиков

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

Ищу годную библиотеку для построения donut-графиков.Желательно иметь функционал клика,который при клике будет отделять фрагмент от остальных по типу куска пирога.Имеется jQuery и D3,можно рассмотреть и плагины к ним.

Comment: так D3 же и [строит пончики](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887193).  Вы [искали](https://www.google.ru/search?q=d3js+donut)?

Comment: посмотрите в галлерее D3.js https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery

Comment: Да,я видел,но они без функционала,мне нужны пончики с кликабельными фрагментами.Фрагмент должен отделятся как кусок пирога при клике

Answer (score 1):

В `google-developers` есть хороший `donut chart` c кликабельными фрагментами и выбором типа отображения:

**[Нажми меня](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart)**